# user-defined events picked up by jQuery datepicker, but works unreliably if there's more than one receiver of an event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-events

I'm using three jQuery datepickers on a web form to input three dates: call them A (a contract's start date), B (the contract's start-of-billing date) and C (the contract's end date).  I do not impose `minDate` or `maxDate` restrictions on A or C, but I do impose one on B: its value can only be in the range A..C.

Every time the user changes A or C, an event defined by the code, either `changeContractStartDate` or `changeContractEndDate`, is called on the other two inputs, (1) to make sure that the condition A <= B <= C always holds, and (2) to update the `maxDate` or `minDate` setting of the datepicker for B.

**What does work:**

- The events are always sent when they should be. (I added alert statements, not present in the code below, to test this.)
- When only B needs to be updated in response to an event, it always is.
- The `if` statements around the date-updating statements of all the datepickers always yield the correct result; that is, the alert statements I added to the code are called exactly when the date needs to be updated.

**What does not work:** Most of the time, when I change A to be later than B and C, C is updated but B isn't. (I once noticed that B was updated but C wasn't.)

**Another observation:** Assume that A is 10, B is 12, and C is 14, where the numers are days of the same month.  If I now change A to 15, C also changes to 15, but B remains 12. However, when I then change C to 18, B *now* changes to 15, without the corresponding alert being called. *This leads me to suspect a bug in datepicker,* where its internal representation of B was updated correctly in the first step, but the displayed value remains the same -- until, in the second step, it is updated to match the internal value, for some reason unknown to me.

Is there perhaps some extra event I should call in the handlers of the `changeContractStartDate` or `changeContractEndDate` events, to make sure the displayed value matches the datepicker's internal value, or something?

I've tested this in Firefox v26 on Linux, on Firefox v35.0.1 on Windows, and on Chrome 40.0.2214.115 on Windows. The behaviour is the same on all versions.

Here's the code:

```
/* get the initial values for the dates */
var contractStartDate  = jQuery('input:hidden#contract-start-date').val()   /* A */
var invoicingStartDate = jQuery('input:hidden#invoicing-start-date').val()  /* B */
var contractEndDate    = jQuery('input:hidden#contract-end-date').val()     /* C */

/* datepicker for A (contract start date) */
jQuery('#contract_start_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  defaultDate: contractStartDate,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    /* when the user picks a different date, inform datepickers for B and C
       via event changeContractStartDate */
    var newContractStartDate = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('#contract_end_date').datepicker().trigger('changeContractStartDate', [ newContractStartDate ]);
    jQuery('#invoicing_start_date').datepicker().trigger('changeContractStartDate', [ newContractStartDate ]);
  }
})
.datepicker('setDate', contractStartDate)
.on('changeContractEndDate', function(event, newContractEndDate) {
  var contractStartDate = jQuery(this).val();
  if (newContractEndDate < contractStartDate) {
    /* if new C is smaller than A, change A to C */
    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', newContractEndDate);
  }
})

/* datepicker for B (invoicing start date) */
jQuery('#invoicing_start_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  defaultDate: invoicingStartDate,
  minDate: contractStartDate,
  maxDate: contractEndDate,
})
.datepicker('setDate', invoicingStartDate)
.on('changeContractEndDate', function(event, newContractEndDate) {
  var invoicingStartDate = jQuery(this).val();
  if (newContractEndDate < invoicingStartDate) {
    /* if new C is smaller than B, change B to C */
    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', newContractEndDate);
  }
  jQuery(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', newContractEndDate);
})
.on('changeContractStartDate', function(e, newContractStartDate) {
  var invoicingStartDate = jQuery(this).val();
  if (invoicingStartDate < newContractStartDate) {
    /* if new A is greater than B, change B to A */
    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', newContractStartDate);
  }
  jQuery(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', newContractStartDate);
})

/* datepicker for C (contract end date) */
jQuery('#contract_end_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  defaultDate: contractEndDate,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    /* when the user picks a different date, inform datepickers for A and B
       via event changeContractEndDate */
    var newContractEndDate = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('#contract_start_date').datepicker().trigger('changeContractEndDate', [ newContractEndDate ]);
    jQuery('#invoicing_start_date').datepicker().trigger('changeContractEndDate', [ newContractEndDate ]);
  }
})
.datepicker('setDate', contractEndDate)
.on('changeContractStartDate', function(e, newContractStartDate) {
  var contractEndDate = jQuery(this).val();
  if (contractEndDate < newContractStartDate) {
    /* if new A is greater than C, change C to A */
    jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', newContractStartDate);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my question, I wrote: "Is there perhaps some extra event I should call in the handlers of the changeContractStartDate or changeContractEndDate events, to make sure the displayed value matches the datepicker's internal value, or something?"

I just found the answer: yes, I do have to call something after the

```
jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', whatever)
```

statements; namely,

```
jQuery(this).datepicker('show');
```

For some reason unknown to me, when a datepicker's date is changed via the `setDate` setter, it sometimes does change the displayed value, and sometimes doesn't. To make sure, add the `show` statement as given above.